# How to set item details in Paypal SDK createOrder?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Following this: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#2-add-the-paypal-javascript-sdk-to-your-web-page

I want to add more details to my item, reading the reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-purchase_unit_request
I have added this code:

```
 createOrder: function(data, actions) {


                            return actions.order.create({
                                intent: 'CAPTURE',
                                purchase_units: [{
                                    description: 'something',
                                    amount: {
                                        value: 50
                                    },
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            name: 'my_product',
                                            unit_amount: 50,
                                            quantity: 1,
                                            sku: 'custom_sku',
                                            category: 'DIGITAL_GOODS'
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }]
                            });


                        }
```

But is giving a 400 error (bad request)
An easy way to test that is here:
https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

The problem is the "items" key/value, removing that it works fine, does somebody know what is wrong and how to set custom details to my order? (I'm expecting to receive that data later to validate the order)